# How to mock using patch relative paths?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have something like this in a python test file:

```
from mock import patch,
from ..monkey import ook
[...]
@patch('monkey.ook', Mock(return_value=None))
def test_run_ook (self, mock_ook):
    self.assertIsNone(ook())
    mock_ook.run.assert_called_once_with('')
```

When I run this test, I get a `ImportError: No module named monkey`.  Clearly, the path I am patching is not right.  However, I am not sure how to make it right without messing with `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH`.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From what I gather, with mock, you *need* to provide a dotted name when patching. Luckily, every module has access to a special module-level variable `__name__` which contains the module's name. Using this, if you want to patch variables local to your module, you *should* be able to do something like the following:

```py
import mock
import unittest

ook = lambda: "the ook"


class OokTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_ook(self):
        with mock.patch(__name__ + '.ook', return_value=None):
            self.assertIsNone(ook())
        self.assertEquals(ook(), "the ook")

    # the patch decorator should work the same way, I just tend to use the
    # context manager out of personal preference
    @mock.patch(__name__ + '.ook', return_value=None)
    def test_ook_2(self, mock_ook):
        self.assertIsNone(ook())
```

Assuming you've saved that file as `quicktest.py`, the unit tests give this result:

```
$ python -m unittest quicktest
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

And of course, `from a.b import c` gives you a plain variable `c` in your package, so this same mechanism should work.

Comment: you can also use `__package__` instead of `_name__` to access the current directory.

Comment: this only change/patch the function in the test module, meaning the original imported function in the src.py will not be effected(patched)

Answer (score 30):

I used Dan Passaro's solution till I came across this one using [`patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) – which looks even better to me:

```
from unittest.mock import patch,
from .. import monkey
[...]
@patch.object(monkey, 'ook', Mock(return_value=None))
def test_run_ook (self, mock_ook):
    self.assertIsNone(monkey.ook())
    mock_ook.run.assert_called_once_with('')
```

Advantages:

- No need for the boilerplate code that is `__name__ + '.object_to_be_mocked'`
- All dependencies of the test case are clearly stated at the beginning of the file as `import` statements.
- In cases where the dotted name of the object you're trying to mock out is longer (say "amazon.jungle.monkey.ook") and you therefore write `@patch.object(amazon.jungle.monkey, 'ook', …)`, your IDE's static code analysis can make sure that at least `amazon.jungle.monkey` is a valid variable since you didn't write the whole thing as a string `'amazon.jungle.monkey.ook'`.

Disadvantages:

- You cannot do `from ..monkey import ook` but need to do `from .. import monkey` and access `ook` through `monkey`, i.e. `monkey.ook`. In cases where I need to write this often I will add `ook = monkey.ook` to the beginning of my tests for convenience. (Or even to the import statements in case I never need to mock out this particular property of `monkey`.)

Comment: Probably, there are several disadvantages, but **in general it is very useful approach for many cases**! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Building on the accepted answer, I believe that this is the cleanest way to achieve desired goal:

```
from mock import patch
from .. import monkey

@patch(monkey.__name__+'.ook', Mock(return_value=None))
def test_run_ook (self, mock_ook):
    self.assertIsNone(monkey.ook())
    mock_ook.run.assert_called_once_with('')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best way (or even recommended), but one way is to use something like:

```
from mock import patch,
from ..monkey import ook
[...]

package_base = __package__.rsplit('.', 1)[0]

@patch('{0}.monkey.ook'.format(package_base), Mock(return_value=None))
def test_run_ook (self, mock_ook):
    self.assertIsNone(ook())
    mock_ook.run.assert_called_once_with('')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `from ..monkey import ook` from a module `pkg1.pgk2.mymodule` what you end up is with `pkg1.pgk2.mymodule.ook`.

That is now `ook` is in the namespace of the module where you performed the `from ... import ...`. And that is the target that you need to patch.

So you just patch `pkg1.pkg2.mymodule.ook`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch # mypackage.mymodule.patch
from ..monkey import ook        # mypacket.mymodule.ook

with patch("pkg1.pgk2.mymodule.ook"):
   ....
```

As pointed out by others, if you are patching from the same module where you did the import then you can use `__name__` to get the dotted package name, but if you are patching from another module you need to spell it out.

Just remember that whatever you import is patcheable from target `modulethatimports.nameimported`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this comes from the fact that you don't import `monkey` but instead import `ook`. If you import monkey from `..` then it should work. Otherwise, just call patch on `ook`.

Comment: When I do that, I get `TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: ook` from Mock.

Comment: Then do import `monkey` instead of import `ook` from it so your original patch will actually work.

Comment: It will still not work since `monkey` doesn't seem to be found in one of directories in sys.path. (That's why Sardathrion is doing the relative import I guess.) In fact, the patch decorator doesn't care about your imports since it will import the module in question itself.

Answer (score -1):

Use the complete path for the import. For example, if you have this filesystem:

- root/

  - dumy/

    - foo/

      - module.py
  - dummy2/

    - module2.py

You can import module.py from module2.py using:

```
from root.dummy.foo import module
```

Comment: -1 as this does not answer my question.  I wanted to know how to use it with **relative** paths and **not absolute paths**.

Comment: @Sardathrion Ok, but you don't say anything about this in your question... You only say you don't want to use sys.path