# python @patch custom patched object not updating

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, patch, python-mock

I want to patch a function(`func_to_be_mocked` ) returning class object (`ReturnValue`) with my own mocked version (`ReturnValueMock`). The function I want to test(`func_to_be_tested`) is setting some values on the object. But my mocked object is not getting updated and showing the deafult values. (i.e. assert statement in test is failing). What am I missing?

to_test.py

```
class ReturnValue():
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = ""

class ToTest():

  def func_to_be_mocked(self):
    return ReturnValue()

  def func_to_be_tested(self):
    ret_val = self.func_to_be_mocked()
    ret_val.a = "set"
```

test.py

```
from mock import patch
import unittest
from .to_test import ToTest

class ReturnValueMock():
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = ""


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.ret_val = ReturnValueMock()

  @patch("to_test.ToTest.func_to_be_mocked")
  def test(self, mocked_func):
    mocked_func.return_val = self.ret_val
    ToTest().func_to_be_tested()
    assert self.ret_val == "set"
```

Thing tried so far

- Added print statements to verify that the object in function under test is same as the one I am providing as mock (Object hash code code are same)

Comment: You imported the code using relative import, but patched an absolute module path. I like to place tests in a separate folder along side the source and import using an absolute path. If you really need to do this consider patching the object instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23844656/3280538

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using the absolute path, but still the same error :-( :-(

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
# run.py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import PropertyMock, patch
from datetime import datetime


class ReturnValue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = ''


class ToTest:
    def func_to_be_mocked(self):
        return ReturnValue()

    def func_to_be_tested(self):
        ret_val = self.func_to_be_mocked()
        ret_val.a = 'set'
        return ret_val


class ReturnValueMock:
    def __init__(self, a: str):
        self.a = a


class Tests(TestCase):
    def test(self):
        # just demo before patching
        obj = ToTest()
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(obj.func_to_be_tested(), ReturnValue))

        first_result = ReturnValueMock('first')
        self.assertEqual(first_result.a, 'first')

        second_result = ReturnValueMock('second')
        self.assertEqual(second_result.a, 'second')

        # let's change result of func_to_be_mocked() from ReturnValue to ReturnValueMock
        with patch(
          # change run to your module...
          'run.ToTest.func_to_be_mocked',
          side_effect=[first_result, second_result]
        ):
            self.assertTrue(isinstance(obj.func_to_be_tested(), ReturnValueMock))
            self.assertEqual(first_result.a, 'set')

            self.assertTrue(isinstance(obj.func_to_be_tested(), ReturnValueMock))
            self.assertEqual(second_result.a, 'set')

#============================= test session starts #==============================
#collecting ... collected 1 item
#
#run.py::Tests::test PASSED                                             [100%]
#
#============================== 1 passed in 2.87s #===============================
```